# Vue JS Page loading issues on IPhone devices using both browser ( Safari & Chrome ), Can't open this page, Symfony (4.4) + Vue JS (v2.5)

Tags: iphone, laravel, vue.js, symfony, safari

My app is built on Symfony (4.4) + Vue JS(v2.5)

I am having an issue with iPhone devices on both safari and chrome browsers, the page reloads automatically after 10 to 30 sec. And after some tries give an error:  Can't open this page. Also, I can see the page load indicator on the browser is not completed and the page reloads automatically.

Since I cannot figure out where precisely the glitch is, I am unable to share a piece of code. Please let me know the required things to share with you.

**my package.json content**

```
{
"devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^2.0.0",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.6",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.5",
    "vue-loader": "^15",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
},
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"private": true,
"browserslist": [
    "defaults"
],
"scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress",
    "build-noprogress": "encore production"
},
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "swiped-events": "^1.1.4"
}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by adding a Component Lazy loading to avoid High Memory usage.
I will later post the code later.
If anyone needs urgent can contact me.

```
me@abdulrehman.pk
```